# why $-\log(x) $ is a valuation like $v_p(x)$?

Tags: valuation-theory

Why $\log$ is used in the definition of valuation?

I can not understand how $\log(x)$ gives rational value always.

We know that p-adic valuation of $x \in \Bbb Q$ is given by
$$|x|_p=p^{-v_p(x)}.$$
We also define valuation to be $-\log(x)$.

Also we know that $v_p(x) \in \Bbb Z \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

My question-

Why $-\log(x) $  is a valuation i.e., why $|x|_p=p^{-\log(x)}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ be a rational number. Then by fundamental theorem of arithmetic you can uniquely factorize

$$|x| = \prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}p^{\nu_p(x)}$$

where $\nu_p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}$. You can define $p$-adic absolute value by $|x|_p = p^{-\nu_p(x)}$. The idea is that sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers is convergent to $0$ if and only if "*$x_n$ are more divisible by $p$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$*".

You can also define equivalent absolute value by $|x|'_p=\beta^{-\nu_p(x)}$ for $\beta>1$, but it defines the same topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ (which is precisely why we call it equivalent).

I don't know any definition of $p$-adic absolute value that involves the usual logarithm of some base.

**Edit after OP's clarification.**

The OP's question is an issue with interpreting problem 28 on page 26 of  F. Gouvea's book "p-adic numbers, An Introduction".

Fix a field $K$. The point of the exercise is to show that the map

$$\big\{\mbox{non-archimedean absolute values on }K\big\}\in |-|\mapsto -\log(|x|)\in \big\{\mbox{ discrete valuations on }K\big\}$$

is a bijective correspondence, which is a correct mathematical result.

Note that you missed the fact that logarithm is applied to absolute value in the exercise.

Let me illustrate this by using $p$-adic absolute value.

$$|x|_p = p^{-\nu_p(x)}$$

where $\nu_p$ is $p$-adic valuation (defined in the first part of my answer). Exercise told us **to apply the logarithm to an absolute value $|x|_p$ and multiply the result by $(-1)$**. Hence we obtain

$$-\log(|x|_p) = -\left(-\nu_p(x)\right)\cdot \log(p) = \log(p)\cdot \nu_p(x)$$

so in this way we recover $p$-adic valuation (up to positive multiplicative constant, which yields equivalent valuation).

On the other hand in the formulation of your question **you applied logarithm to $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and expected**

> $|x|_p = p^{-\log(x)}$

**to be a $p$-adic absolute value**, which under any reasonable circumstances does not take place and is not defined for $x<0$.

Comment: My question was- How we are using $\log(x)$ instead of $v_p(x)$ in some places?

Comment: You wrote "we also define $\nu_p(x) = -\log(x)$", which is incorrect. I think that we don't use $\log(x)$ instead of $\nu_p(x)$. At least not in authoritative sources. Can you provide some reference for this?

Comment: Yes,  go  to page $26$ of F. Gouvea's book, problem $28$ from this link (see [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Wb7uCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=p-adic+absolute+value+%7Cx%7C_p%3Dp%5E%7B-log(x)%7D&source=bl&ots=5YW2UOavLC&sig=ACfU3U1Tj5OmZt9JtxoKTAg6WIAKN4pMfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7sL6GvuflAhWOUn0KHTD8AV0Q6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=p-adic%20absolute%20value%20%7Cx%7C_p%3Dp%5E%7B-log(x)%7D&f=false))

Comment: Ok. I think that I understand the source of your confusion. Please take a look at edited part of my answer.